# how to convert from dataset using in libSVM to fomat data using in weka (*.arff or *.csv)

Tags: csv, dataset, weka, libsvm, arff

I want to use dataset is input data of libSVM for Weka tool. But I don't know how to convert data to format `.arff` or `.csv`.

Followed is some lines in my data file using for libSVM:

Data sample:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can load data in libsvm format into weka. Weka along other formats supports .arff, .csv and .libsvm format.

Just load your file as normal in weka and select .libsvm from the file-type dropdown menu in the bottom right corner of the load-file dialog.

Aftwards you can save the file in any of the supported formats, such as .arff.